# NoneType Error Obtained when Creating Subplots with Python Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

can anyone run the sample code of plotly which creates the subplot? I'm referring to the code on the following website, which gives me a

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" error".
>   https://plot.ly/python/subplots/ (link fixed)

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=800, title_text="Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran exactly your code with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 and it works.

These are the versions I have installed:

```
$ pip freeze
plotly==4.5.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
```

When you get the error, please include the complete error, not only the very last line. It would help to see the exact line where the error happens.

Comment: Thank you. I upgraded the version to plotly 4.5.0. It's working now.